# TDBEdit PopupMenu Default Behaviour

Tags: delphi

There appears to be a change in behaviour between Delphi 5 (yes I know it is very old) and Delphi 10.1 when a TDBEdit control that does NOT have its PupupMenu property set is selected and the Right Mouse Button is clicked. In Delphi 5 TDBEdit's parent controls PopupMenu is presented (assuming of course it has one) but in Delphi 10.1 a 'standard' Windows context menu is presented ['Undo', 'Cut', ... 'Right to left Reading order' etc.].

How can I get Delphi 10.1 to use a TDBEdit control's parent control's PopupMenu if it does not have one explicitly set. The application being migrated has hundereds of forms each with tens of TDBEdit controls and the thought of having to explicitly set each of their PopupMenu properties to that of thire parent control is more than a little daunting!

Comment: Yes, this change in behaviour could be a bit of a pain.  Given the number of forms you've got, are you looking for a solution that involves some kind of run-time fix or a (semi-) automated update of the .DFM files?  Personally, I'd look at using something like the Replace facility in GExpert's `Grep Results` utility to change the .DFMs.

Comment: Indeed. Time is of the essence. The Popup property and OnContextPopup Event documentation provides various combinations of options for handling the automatic or explicit presentation of a popup menu but does not mention the default behaviour of displaying the 'windows' popup menu (which differs depending on the Operating System in use).

Comment: Unless I can find a project\application level option in the IDE to suppress this behaviour I think I am going to have to 'educate' the users to select and field and make sure they then RMB click outside the field to prevent the windows popup appearing instead of the parent controls popup (which has been designed to include options for the currently selected field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple (or, you may say, simplistic) run-time fix for this by using the `OnActiveFormChange` event of your application's `Screen` object.

It's probably easiest to put most of the necessary code in a datamodule which is Used by at least your main form.

For example add the following methods to the datamodule:

```
Uses [...] Forms, DBCtrls;

procedure TdmPopUp.ActiveFormChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FixUpDBEdits(Screen.ActiveForm);
end;

procedure TdmPopUp.FixUpDBEdits(AForm : TForm);

  procedure FixUpDBEdit(ADBEdit : TDBEdit);
  begin
    if ADBEdit.PopupMenu = Nil then
      if ADBEdit.PopupMenu <> AForm.PopupMenu then
        ADBEdit.PopupMenu := AForm.PopupMenu
  end;

  procedure FixUpDBEditsInner(AComponent : TComponent);
  var
    i : Integer;
  begin
    if AComponent is TDBEdit then
      FixUpDBEdit(TDBEdit(AComponent));
    for i := 0 to AComponent.ComponentCount - 1 do
      if AComponent.Components[i] is TDBEdit then
        FixUpDBEdit(TDBEdit(AComponent.Components[i]));
  end;

begin
  FixUpDBEditsInner(AForm);
end;
```

Then, all the additional code you need can go in your main form's OnCreate and OnDestroy:

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveFormChange := Nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveFormChange := dmPopUp.ActiveFormChange;
end;
```

Obviously the "hard work" is done in the `FixUpDBEdit` sub-procedure in the datamodule.  My version simply checks that the DBEdit's `PopUpMenu` is not nil (in case it has been explicitly set to something), that it isn't already set to the enclosing form's `PopUpMenu` and then assigns it to the form's.  This hasn't been soak-tested and may require some finessing, but hopefully should get you going.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Ironically, when each Form's PopupMenu is activated the Form's controls (including any TDBEdits) are examined and their current state ('content' for example) is used to affect the Items shown in the Form's PopupMenu.

Comment: @SLBentall:  Glad to help.  I confess I only did a cursory search of how a TDBEdit's PopUpMenu is set in Delphi Seattle, couldn't find it and decided my "sledgehammer" way could be a way to go.